# What is the best practice for selecting and displaying all values from an 'Appointment' table with a matching userID from a 'User' table?

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli, appointment

I'm very new to coding with MySQLi using PHP.  I'm currently trying to code a simple appointment-user application with 2 tables in my database which I've already input some test values in as shown below.

I am really trying all my best but I don't know everything about MySQLi yet and I'm willing to learn.  I've already spent all of yesterday looking around this site but I haven't come across any previous posts that answered my problem.  Thank you for any help you can offer a newbie like me.

**What I have working so far:**

- I've saved the user's login SESSION in another session.  It works fine and retrieves the correct user row based on their username login.
- The `$_SESSION['appointment']` displays the appointment array for the particular user with the matching userID

**The problem**

- The `$_SESSION['appointment']` ONLY displays the first result of theappointment array for the particular user with the matching userID.
- In my case, it only displays the `$_SESSION['appointment']['date']` = `2016-12-20` for Bob Marley and does not display all his other appointments `2016-12-31` and `2016-12-29` even when it has the same matching `userID = 3`

*How do I display all of a user's related appointment dates if they have a matching `userID` in the 'appointment' table?*

**My database tables:**

> 'users' table:
>
> userID (column 1) // username (column 2) // name (column 3)
>
> 1 // user1 // Bob Dylan
>
> 2 // user2 //  John Lennon
>
> 3 // user3 // Bob Marley

-

> 'appointment' table
>
> 'appointmentID' (column 1) // userID (column 2) // date (column 3)
>
> 1 (appointmentID) // 1 (userID) // 2016-12-07
>
> 2 (appointmentID) // 2 (userID) // 2016-12-15
>
> 3 (appointmentID) // 3 (userID) // 2016-12-20
>
> 4 (appointmentID) // 3 (userID) // 2016-12-31
>
> 5 (appointmentID) // 3 (userID) // 2016-12-29

**My SESSIONS:**

```
 //Displays the array of the user
 $_SESSION['profile'] = displayProfile($_SESSION['user']);

 //Displays the array of the appointment based on the matching userID
 $_SESSION['appointment'] = displayAppointment($_SESSION['profile']['userID']);
```

**My mySQLi functions:**

```
 function displayProfile($username)
 {
     global $ db_con; //my database connection

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=\''.mysqli_escape_string($db_con, $username).'\'';
     $result = $db_con-> query($query);

     //This fetches the associative array for the user row 
     //(i.e. $_SESSION['profile']['userID'] outputs the userID of the user logged into the system
     if ($result->num_rows) { return $result->fetch_assoc();}
 }

  //////////////////////////////

   function displayAppointment($userID)
 {
     global $ db_con; //my database connection

     //This passes the current logged on user's userID into the query.
     //For example, if Bob Marley was currently logged on, the $userID that will be passed is userID = 3.
     $query = 'SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE userID='.$userID;
     $result = $db_con-> query($query);

     //This fetches the associative array for the appointment row with the correct matching userID
     //(i.e. $_SESSION['profile']['userID'] for Bob Marley is '3'
     if ($result->num_rows) { return $result->fetch_assoc();}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you require is to return everything from the function right then you should use

[`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

editenote: becouse he doesnt have the drivers for fetch_all

```
function displayAppointment($userID)
 {
     global $ db_con; //my database connection

     //This passes the current logged on user's userID into the query.
     //For example, if Bob Marley was currently logged on, the $userID that will be passed is userID = 3.
     $query = 'SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE userID='.$userID;
     $result = $db_con-> query($query);

     //This fetches the associative array for the appointment row with the correct matching userID
     //(i.e. $_SESSION['profile']['userID'] for Bob Marley is '3' 
    $resultout=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($resultout, $row);
    }
    return $resultout;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried that already and it gave me the error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()...

Comment: UPDATE:  after poking around the internet I've come across this:  "The variable $stmt is of type mysqli_stmt, not mysqli_result. The mysqli_stmt class doesn't have a method "fetch_assoc()" defined for it."

Comment: Is there a similar or alternative fetch_all() method I can use?

Comment: I'm using a PHPAdmin based database, name is 'scheduleDB'.

Comment: what changes did you make to that code for it to get the above mentioned mysqli_stmt error ? was it my code ?

Comment: I only replaced the 'fetch_assoc()' with your 'fetch_all()' for the 'displayAppointment()` function.  After looking around some more, I found that maybe I don't have the driver installed to be able to use the fetch_all() method.  So I'm now looking for a possibility of using another way that's similar to fetch_all().

Comment: fetch_assoc(); works but it only gets the first row of whatever the matching userID is in the appointment table like I explained in my question above.  All I'm looking for is to get ALL the rows with the matching userID (i.e. '3') in my appointment table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128759/discussion-between-buddhi741-and-5120bee).